# Error while injecting ngCookies?

Tags: angularjs

```
var app = angular.module('mittens',['ui.router','ngCookies']);
```

Isn't above the right way to inject ngCookies? It's throwing this error

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=mittens&p1=Error%3A…0zc%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Flibrary%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A274)(…)
>   https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=mittens&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:modulerr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.9%2F$injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DngCookie%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.4.9%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253DngCookie%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Flibrary%252Fangular.min.js%253A6%253A416%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Flibrary%252Fangular.min.js%253A24%253A186%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520b%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Flibrary%252Fangular.min.js%253A23%253A252)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Flibrary%252Fangular.min.js%253A23%253A495%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Flibrary%252Fangular.min.js%253A38%253A153%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520n%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Flibrary%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A355)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Flibrary%252Fangular.min.js%253A38%253A1)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Flibrary%252Fangular.min.js%253A38%253A170%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520n%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Flibrary%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A355)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Flibrary%252Fangular.min.js%253A38%253A1)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Flibrary%2Fangular.min.js:6:416%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Flibrary%2Fangular.min.js:38:427%0A%20%20%20%20at%20n%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Flibrary%2Fangular.min.js:7:355)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Flibrary%2Fangular.min.js:38:1)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Flibrary%2Fangular.min.js:38:170%0A%20%20%20%20at%20n%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Flibrary%2Fangular.min.js:7:355)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Flibrary%2Fangular.min.js:38:1)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20db%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Flibrary%2Fangular.min.js:41:272)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Flibrary%2Fangular.min.js:19:463)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20zc%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Flibrary%2Fangular.min.js:20:274

```
app.controller('HomeController',['$scope','$http','$cookies',function($scope,$http,$cookies) {}
```

Comment: i hope you have inclded ngCookie in index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled `ngCookies` as `ngCookie` in your real code but corrected it for the question.

Did you click on the admittedly rather long URL?

That will tell you:

> Failed to instantiate module mittens due to:

and then another link which tell you:

> Failed to instantiate module ngCookie due to:

and then another link which takes you to:

> Module 'ngCookie' is not available! You either misspelled the module
>   name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you
>   specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Each of these is accompanied by a stack trace, but the descriptions I've quoted at the top really say it all. `ngCookie` is not available because either you forgot to load the javascript or you misspelled its name.

Now there seems to be some confusion here as your question says you asked for `'ngCookies'`, but the error message says `'ngCookie'` was not found. Check that you didn't autocorrect a misspelling of the name when you posted the question.

Comment: When I exclude 'ngCookies' dependency and load the program then angular-cookie.js is also working.Only after adding the  dependency its giving me the error

Comment: Are you positive that you wrote `ngCookies` in your program? The link to the error page says you used `ngCookie`.

Comment: I am using ngCookies.'angular.module('app', ['ui.router','ngCookies']);

Comment: and, like I said, in your JSFIDDLE link you have 'ngCookie' with no 's' on the end.

Answer (score 1):

Because you forget to load the angular cookies file. Load th file first and then try.

```
<script src="path/to/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-cookie/4.0.0/angular-cookie.js"></script>
```

Finally, load the module in your application by adding it as a dependent module:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngCookies']);
```

With that you're ready to get started!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have refereed library

```
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-cookies.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Make sue you have injected the dependency

```
var miAp = angular.module('miAp', ['ngCookies']);
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/aMhNig8WjWcPbkMAA2nk?p=info)**

Comment: it should be var app = angular.module('mittens',['ui.router','ngCookies'])